# On Netlify I can't get the _redirects or netlify.toml file get to work because of the already generated _redirects from Nuxt

Tags: redirect, nuxt.js, netlify

I have a Nuxt project on Netlify and I'm trying to get my netlify.toml redirects to work but I just can't because when I look at the deployed code Nuxt is already generating a _redirects file that overrides mine with the following content:

/__nuxt_error /.netlify/functions/server 200
/* /.netlify/functions/server 200

I've also tried creating my own _redirects file in the root folder but that isn't even in the deployed source code while the netlify.toml is but that's overwritten.

What can I do so the generate basic _redirects file is not overwriting my custom redirects?

Thanks in advance!